# Closing a pipe invalidates DLL's stdout handle

Tags: windows, delphi, dll, console, stdout

I'm calling a function from an external DLL, which writes its output to stdout. In order to capture the output, I created a monitoring thread where I redirect the stdout to a pipe using `CreatePipe` and `SetStdHandle` (code below). The problem is that this code only works once. If executed more than once, the DLL throws and "Invalid Handle" exception when it tries to output something. I narrowed it down to the `CloseHandle(PipeWrite)` line. If I comment it out, it starts working as intended. Why does closing this pipe permanently invalidate DLL's stdout handle?

```
const
  SecConst: TSecurityAttributes = (nLength: SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes); bInheritHandle: true);
var
  Security: TSecurityAttributes;
  hStdOld, PipeRead, PipeWrite: THandle;
begin
  Security := SecConst;
  CreatePipe(PipeRead, PipeWrite, @Security, 0);
  hStdOld := GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, PipeWrite);

  while not Terminated do
  begin
    if ReadPipe(PipeRead, FOutput) > 0 then
    begin
      Synchronize(SendOutput);
    end;

  end;
  SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hStdOld);
  CloseHandle(PipeRead);
  CloseHandle(PipeWrite); //problematic call
end;
```

Comment: Maybe the dll caches the stdout handle? In that case it will always try to output to the pipe of the first call.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: This is a rather strange way of communicating with a DLL. Are you the author of that DLL? Did you check if the second call to SetStdHandle() succeeds? My guess is that it doesn't.

Comment: I abandoned this approach as soon as I realized it was only working while under debugger.